# connect to database in remote machine through MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to connect to another PC's database through MySQL Workbench6.0

I have added all the related firewall exceptions for all ports in both PCs.

In Workbench i have done settings as

[image]

Is there anything wrong with it?

Is there any more settings i will have to do?

Please help me.

Comment: Meaning of the error message is that `MySQL` service is not running on that system. And are you sure it is the IP of other system. Usually in a LAN that IP is assigned to Router for convenience.

Comment: See also the MySQL channel video about [connectioon creation and trooubble shooting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY&list=PLWx5a9Tn2EvHpwpyDa2oJczpK0ojwJpM5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have set

```
bind-address = 192.168.1.1
```

set in yourr my.cnf.

Also make sure you granted the correct rights

so something like for just your client machine

```
grant all privilege on *.* to `username`@`your-pc-id` identified by 'password'
```

or

```
grant all on *.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

for all hosts.

Comment: sir, where is my.cnf situated?

Comment: @AngryTiger well not sure what your host machine is but probably /etc/mysql/my.cnf . Dont forget to restart the mysql server after you change that. Btw do be carefull because everywhere you connect to that db you cannot use 127.0.0.1 or localhost anymore

Comment: i got the file my-default.ini ... Its read only... should i directly write bind-adress in it?

Comment: @AngryTiger first search if it is not already there. Probably will read bind-address = 127.0.0.1 otherwise you should be able to add it. But i gather that you are running it on a windows machine ? If so i have no experience running mysql on a windows machine so i cannot be sure

Comment: and sir, final question , where should i write this command??? grant all privilege on *.* to `username`@`your-pc-id` identified by 'password'

Comment: That is an sql statement you have to do that on your server in your mysql console. But make sure you replace the placeholders with the data you want so username is root, pc id is 192.168.1.1 and password is the password you connect with

Comment: grant all on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by ''; if password is blank is it correct??

Comment: GRANT ALL on *.* to 'root@%'; i think but im gone now so good luck

Comment: when i run this i get message... cant find any matching row in the user table